# Why does this WSAIoctl call to load AcceptEx return 10022?

Tags: delphi, winsock2

I'm trying to load an AcceptEx function pointer, per code converted from Microsoft's IOCPSERVEREX.CPP example, which is essentially the same as the sample code on the microsoft.com AcceptEx() page.  I'm using Delphi 6, hence the inline Winsock2 definitions.  I've stripped everything down to this small example, but WSAIoctl always returns error 10022, and I can't figure out why.

```
program test;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses windows, winsock;

type
  GUID = packed record
    D1: DWORD;
    D2: DWORD;
    D3: DWORD;
    D4: array[0..7] of BYTE;
    end;

  PAddrInfo = ^addrinfo;
  addrinfo = packed record
    ai_flags, ai_family, ai_socktype, ai_protocol: integer;
    ai_addrlen: Cardinal;
    ai_canonname: PAnsiChar;
    ai_addr: PSockAddrIn;
    ai_next: PAddrInfo;
    end;

const
  AI_PASSIVE = $01;
  IOC_WS2 = $08000000;
  IOC_OUT = $40000000;
  IOC_IN = $80000000;
  IOC_INOUT = (IOC_IN or IOC_OUT);
  SIO_GET_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER = 6 or IOC_WS2 or IOC_INOUT;
  WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED = $01;
  WSAID_ACCEPTEX: GUID = (D1:$b5367df1; D2:$cbac; D3:$11cf; D4:($95, $ca, $00, $80, $5f, $48, $a1, $92)); // GUID to Microsoft specific extensions

function GetAddrInfo(nodename, servname: PAnsiChar; pHints: PAddrInfo; out res: PAddrInfo): integer; stdcall; external 'ws2_32.dll' name 'getaddrinfo';
function WSAIoctl(const s: TSocket; dwIoControlCode: DWORD; lpvInBuffer: Pointer; cbInBuffer: DWORD; lpvOutBuffer: Pointer; cbOutBuffer: DWORD;
  lpcbBytesReturned: LPDWORD; AOverlapped: Pointer; lpCompletionRoutine: pointer): LongInt; stdcall; external 'ws2_32.dll' name 'WSAIoctl';
function WSASocketA(af, iType, protocol: Integer; lpProtocolInfo: pointer; grp, dwFlags: DWORD): TSocket; stdcall; external 'ws2_32.dll' name 'WSASocketA';

var
  wsaData: TWSADATA;
  g_hIOCP: THANDLE;
  hints: addrinfo;
  g_sdListen: TSOCKET;
  addrlocal: PAddrInfo;
  P: pointer; Bytes: dword;

begin
if WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), wsaData) <> 0 then writeln('WSAStartup failed');
g_hIOCP := CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, 0, 0, 0);
if g_hIOCP = 0 then writeln('CreateIoCompletionPort failed');
fillchar(hints, sizeof(hints), 0);
hints.ai_flags  := AI_PASSIVE;
hints.ai_family := AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype := SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol := IPPROTO_IP;
if getaddrinfo('localhost', '80', PAddrInfo(@hints), addrlocal) <> 0  then writeln('getaddrinfo failed');
if addrlocal = nil then writeln('no addrlocal');
g_sdListen := WSASocketA(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP, nil, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);
if g_sdListen = INVALID_SOCKET then writeln('WSASocketA failed');
if bind(g_sdListen, addrlocal^.ai_addr^, integer(addrlocal^.ai_addrlen)) = SOCKET_ERROR then writeln('bind failed');
if listen(g_sdListen, 5) = SOCKET_ERROR then writeln('listen failed');
g_hIOCP := CreateIoCompletionPort(THANDLE(g_sdListen), g_hIOCP, 0, 0);
if g_hIOCP = 0 then writeln('CreateIoCompletionPort failed');
if WSAIoctl(g_sdListen, SIO_GET_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER, @WSAID_ACCEPTEX, sizeof(WSAID_ACCEPTEX), @P, SizeOf(P), @Bytes, nil, nil) = SOCKET_ERROR then
  writeln('AcceptEx failed to load: ', WSAGetLastError);
write('exit:'); readln;
end.
```

Comment: You declared `GUID` wrong, the 2nd and 3rd fields need to be `Word` instead of `DWord`. Or use Delphi's existing built-in `TGuid` type instead. And your records should not be `packed`.

Comment: Thanks.  I could have sworn I cut-and-pasted that stuff from elsewhere.